# In magento how to access disabled categories through url

Tags: magento

I need to create a category and make it as disable(This category should not visible in front end anywhere) but i want to access that category page through it s Url.Is it possible?

Comment: This is probably better asked on [magento.se]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not disable the category. from admin just edit it to

```
Include in Navigation Menu : No
Is Anchor : No
```

still you can access the category, but no link on frontend

Comment: Are you sure by doing like this that category wont display at any place in front end or else only at navigation menu @Asif hhh

Comment: Also make "Is Anchor" : No, and m sure, you can test it.

Comment: From where i can get that category url to verify @Asif hhh

Comment: well before unlinking the category, you can keep its url. the url formate is like, http://www.domain.com/identifier.html this identifier/url-key can be found from edit page of product.

Comment: I cant find the exact url of my disabled category.i m getting page not found error only@Asif hhh